# A proof on the connectedness of the product space of some connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness, product-space

I am trying to show that the product space of some connected spaces is also connected, and I am not sure whether I am right or not. Here is my proof:

**Proof :** Suppose that $\left\{X_\lambda\right\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a family of connected spaces and $X_0=\Pi X_\lambda$ is the product space. Denote the $\lambda$'th projection by $P_\lambda$, and by the axiom of choice, $P_\lambda$ is surjective. Suppose that $X_0$ is not connected, then $X_0=U\cup V$, where $U,V$ are disjoint non-void clopen sets, then certainly $P_\lambda\left(U\right)$ and $P_\lambda\left(V\right)$ are both non-void for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Then if for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$, $P_\lambda\left(U\right)\cap P_\lambda\left(V\right)\neq \varnothing$, there will be some $x\in X$ such that $P_\lambda\left(x\right)\in P_\lambda\left(U\right)\cap P_\lambda\left(V\right)$ for every $\lambda\in\Lambda$, which implies that $x\in U\cap V$ and contradicts the hypothesis that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Thus there shall be some $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$ such that $P_{\lambda_0}\left(U\right)\cap P_{\lambda_0}\left(U\right)= \varnothing$, and since $P_{\lambda_0}$ is surjective, $P_{\lambda_0}\left(U\right)\cup P_{\lambda_0}\left(V\right)= X_{\lambda_0}$. Since $P_{\lambda_0}$ is open, both $P_{\lambda_0}\left(U\right)$ and $ P_{\lambda_0}\left(V\right)$are open and thus are both clopen, which contradicts the connectedness of $X_{\lambda_0}$.

Am I right? Could you please help me?

Comment: No, the proof is more subtle than that. If it were correct, it would also prove that the product of connected spaces with the box topology is connected, which it does not have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is not right.

From the assumption

> there will be some $x \in X$ such that $P_{\lambda}(x) \in P_{\lambda}(U) \cap P_{\lambda}(V)$ for every $\lambda \in \Lambda$

you incorrectly conclude that

> which implies that $x \in U \cap V$.

To see why this is wrong, consider the subsets

$$\begin{align*}
U & = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y < x \} \\
V & = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geqslant x \} \\
\end{align*}$$

of the product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Clearly $(x, y) = (0, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a point satisfying $x \in \pi_x(U) \cap \pi_x(V)$ and $y \in \pi_y(U) \cap \pi_y(V)$, but $(x, y) \notin U$.

Comment: Thank you very much!